# How to copy heap array totally in c?

Tags: c, struct, heapsort

Hi during my homework I am having a hard time copying the whole heap to another.
I want to get numbers, make heap sort, and finally print it in order.
To protect my heap from printing numbers in the order I want to move stored numbers to a temporary
heap.
It is part of the code I made but it does not work well. Also, I tried it by using strcpy function, but it didn't work.

```
typedef struct {
 int key; 
}element;
element maxheap[maxelements];
element minheap[maxelements]; 
element copyheap[maxelements];
```

If for example I make maxheap and to make empty copyheap the same as maxheap, what is the right way? I thought it could be done by

```
copyheap=maxheap;
```

Here is my full code.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>

#include<time.h> 
#define maxelements 1000001
typedef struct {
     int key; 
}element;
int maxn=0,minn=0 ;
int totalnum=0 ; //numbers i got finally from input.txt
element maxheap[maxelements];
element minheap[maxelements]; 
element copyheap[maxelements]; 

void insertmaxheap(element item, int *maxn); 
void insertminheap(element item , int *minn); 
element deletemaxheap(int *maxn); 
element deleteminheap(int *minn); 

int main(int argc, char* argv[]){
     double start,end; 
     start= (double)clock()/CLOCKS_PER_SEC; 
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
     int i,num,j ;
     int maxtemp,mintemp;
     element newitem,item;//element to print 
     char arr[8]; 
     char insert[]="INSERT"; 
     char ascend[]="ASCEND"; 
     char descend[]="DESCEND"; 
     if(argc !=2) 
     {
         printf("usage: ./hw2 input_filename"); 
     }  
     FILE *fp =fopen(argv[1],"r"); 
    // FILE *result= fopen("hw2_result.txt", "w"); 
     if(fp==NULL){
         printf("The input file does not exist.\n");
     }
     while(!feof(fp)){ //find max capacity to allocate heap
         i=fscanf(fp,"%s",arr); 
         totalnum++; 
     }
     
    // maxheap=(element*)malloc(sizeof(int)*(totalnum+1)); 
     //minheap=(element*)malloc(sizeof(int)*(totalnum+1)); 
     //copyheap=(element*)malloc(sizeof(int)*(totalnum+1)); 

 
 while(!feof(fp)){
    i= fscanf(fp,"%s %d",arr,&num); //파일의 줄 개수를 구해서 그것만큼 할 당
    //totalnum++;  
     if (!strcmp(arr,insert)){//putting num into maxheap and minheap 
        newitem.key=num ;
        insertmaxheap(newitem, &maxn); 
        insertminheap(newitem, &minn); 
      }
     if (!strcmp(arr,ascend)){
        //copy minheap to copyheap and then use  
        copyheap=minheap;
        mintemp=minn;
        printf("%d is total number and i will ascend\n", minn); 
        for(j=0; j<minn;j++){
             item=deleteminheap(&minn); 
             printf("%d ",item.key);  
            
        }
        minn=mintemp; 
      }
      printf("\n"); 
     if (!strcmp(arr,descend)){
         //copy maxheap to copyheap and then use
         copyheap=maxheap;  
         maxtemp=maxn;
         printf("%d is total number and i will descend\n", maxn); 
         for(j=0;j<maxn;j++){
         item= deletemaxheap(&maxn); 
         printf("%d ",item.key );
             
         }
         maxn=maxtemp; 
      }
      printf("\n"); 
 }
 

/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////


 //free(maxheap); 
 //free(minheap); 
 //free(copyheap); 
 fclose(fp);
 end=(((double)clock())/CLOCKS_PER_SEC);
 printf("output written to hw2_result.txt.\n"); 
 printf("running time: %1f\n", (end-start)); 
}

void insertmaxheap(element item, int *maxn){
     int i; 
     i=++(*maxn); 
      while((i!=1)&&(item.key>maxheap[i/2].key)){
         maxheap[i]=maxheap[i/2]; 
         i/=2; 
      }
      maxheap[i]=item; 
}
void insertminheap(element item , int *minn){
     int i; 
     i=++(*minn);
     while((i!=1)&&(item.key<minheap[i/2].key)){
         minheap[i]=minheap[i/2]; 
         i/=2; 
     }
     minheap[i]=item;
}
element deletemaxheap(int *maxn){
     //copy it to copyheap first
     int parent, child; 
     parent=1;
     child=2 ;
     element item,temp; 
      
     item=copyheap[1]; 
     temp=copyheap[(*maxn)--]; 
      
     while(child<=*maxn){
         if((child<*maxn)&&(copyheap[child].key<copyheap[child+1].key))child++;
         if(temp.key>=copyheap[child].key)break;
         copyheap[parent]=copyheap[child]; 
         parent=child;
         child*=2;  
     }
     copyheap[parent]=temp; 
     return item; 
     
}
element deleteminheap(int *minn){
     //copy it to copyheap first
     int parent,child; 
     parent=1;
     child=2 ;
     element item,temp;
     item = copyheap[1]; 
     temp= copyheap[(*minn)--]; 
     
     while(child<=*minn){
         if((child<*minn)&&(copyheap[child].key>copyheap[child+1].key))child++; 
         if(item.key<=copyheap[child].key)break;
         copyheap[parent]=copyheap[child]; 
         parent=child; 
         child*=2 ;
     }
     
     copyheap[parent]=temp;
     return item;
}
```

Comment: `strcpy` is the wrong tool here, because it's for copying strings, not arbitrary arrays of structs. Try `memcpy` instead. For more help, please show some actual code, not just your data declarations.

Comment: The whole code is little bit long but I will edit my question would it be ok for you? @Gereon

Comment: Most of the code is unrelated to the copying problem you've stated. Please reduce it to that part, and again, check `memcpy` which does exactly what you need.

Comment: memcpy is the way to go when dealing with pointer related stuff. This should work memcopy(&copyheap,&minheap,sizeof(minheap)).